# Counting and permuting elements in a list

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

```
list.1 <- list(a=c(0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.12), 
             b=c(0.1,0.2), 
             c=c(0.3,0.1,0.2), 
             d=c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5))
```

and I would like to generate a new list with random (permuted) values from `list.1`, my approach is the following:

```
rand.list <- lapply(list.1, FUN=function(x) replicate(10, sample(x,1)))
```

However, if the length of an element in the list is less than a number, e.g 4, then I would like to use also other elements (previous and next) in the list for calculating the permutations, taking in account that the length of all these elements is > 4. For example, in my list, `length(list.1$b) == 2` and `length(list.1$c)==3`, I would like to use for randomising `list.1$b` values from `list.1$a` and `list.1$c`, and for randomising `list.1$c` values from `list.1$b` and `list.1$d`. Any ideas how to achieve this??

Many thanks in advance

UPDATE

A solution provide for @dardisco:

```
l2 <- list()
ll1 <- length(list.1)
length(l2) <- ll1
set.seed(4)
for (i in 1:ll1){
   vec1 <- list.1[[i]]
    jl <- 1;jr<-1; #i've added two counters one for left one for right
    while (length(vec1) < 4){
       if(i==1) {
          vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i+jr]])
          jr <- jr+1
        } else if (i==ll1 || jr+i==ll1 ){ #to avoid out of boundaries, so many elements with less than 4 elements close to the end
           vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i-jl]])
           jl <- jl+1
    }else {
           vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i-jl]], list.1[[i+jr]])
               jl <- jl+1
        jr <- jr+1
        } 
 } 
   l2[[i]] <- sample2(vec1, 10, replace=TRUE)   
}
```

Comment: This will be a case to use a for-loop. In using `lapply there is no sense of "nearest or adjacent other list" inside the function `FUN`.

Comment: @DWin unless you wanna do the cludgy `sapply(seq_along(list.1), ...)`.

Comment: True enough, and no difference in logic or efficiency.

Comment: Could I use something like `for (i in 1:length(list.1)){if length(list.1)[i] > 4 {replicate(10, sample(list.1[i],1))}}`? However, for the previous and next, should I set up a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from @DWins advice - is this what you're looking for?

```
l2 <- list()
length(l2) <- length(list.1)
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:length(list.1)){
    if ( length(list.1[[i]]) >=4 ){
        l2[[i]] <- sample(list.1[[i]], 10, replace=TRUE)
        } else {
            l2[[i]] <- sample(c(list.1[[i]],list.1[[i-1]],list.1[[i+1]]),
                                10, replace=TRUE)
            }
    }
```

Note that this assumes the first and last elements in the list have >=4 elements.

**Update**

In light of your comment - start with an example which better illustrates the problem:

```
list.1 <- list(a=letters[1:2],
               b=letters[3],
               c=letters[10:14],
               d=letters[25:26])
```

then

```
l2 <- list()
ll1 <- length(list.1)
### ll1 = length of list.1
length(l2) <- ll1
set.seed(4)
for (i in 1:ll1){
### vec1 = default vector from which to sample
    vec1 <- list.1[[i]]
### j = counter for position relative to current
    j <- 1
### if sample size <4 (the threshold) then include additional elements in list until >=4
### change this to 50 if required, as in:
### while (length(vec1) <50){
    while (length(vec1) <4){
### check if at first element
        if(i==1) {
### keep adding successive elements from list.1 to end of vec1
            vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i+j]])
            j <- j+1
### if at last element, add preceding elements
        } else if (i==ll1 ){
            vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i-j]])
            j <- j+1
        } else {
### you could add both in one step, like so:
### vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i-j]], list.1[[i+j]])
### j <- j+1
### }
### or do it in two steps as below:
###
### k = counter to indicate moving forward or back 
            k <- 1
### if odd, add next element
            if (!k %% 2==0){
                vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i+j]])
            } else {
### if even, add preceding element and increment counter for relative position
                vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i-j]])
                j <- j+1
            }
            k <- k+1
        }
    }
    l2[[i]] <- sample(vec1, 10, replace=TRUE)
}
```

This should do what you want, although there may be a prettier way. Gains from vectorisation are likely to be modest at best.

Comment: thanks @dardisco, but it is not sure that first and last elements in the list have >=4 elements. Actually, I would like to iterate through the list because add the -1 or the +1 elements sometimes could not be enough and I would need go to -2 and +2 and so on. Should I initialise a counter or something similar? Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: thanks again @dardisco, my last question, could be possible add precedent also element in `vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i+j]])`, I have tried with `vec1 <- c(vec1, list.1[[i+j]], list.1[[i-j]])` but I got an error. Many many thanks for your help

Comment: OK, that should be it. You need separate rules for dealing with he first and last elements of the list. Result looks rather like `C++`; if your lists are v. long, converting to same would probably show the biggest improvements in speed.

Comment: Brilliant!! @dardisco, It works as I want, could you explain to me a little bit more what `if (!k %% 2==0)` does? and my list is very long more than 9,000 in length with elements very different in size, and I want to set the threshold around 50 instead of 4. Many thanks again

Comment: `%%` is modulo - the remainder from division, try `1:4 %% 2`. `!` is logical `NOT` which will coerce the `1,0` to logical. I'm using this as a counter for: *first add next element in list, then preceding, then increment k, then repeat*. Note that my example will need tweaking if a number of elements near the ends are much <50 - i.e. you'll need to check whether you're at the end of the list (`list.1`) each time before adding the next element. This should be a straightforward extension if required.

Comment: thanks @dardisco, you are right about the elements near the end, I have an addition to your code for avoiding what you mention, but I've used your one-step approach, could you take a look and give me your opinion?

Comment: Looks OK to me; real question is - does it work for your data?

Comment: I think so, actually the results look fine. But if you had time I would like to see your approach for the problem when there are many elements <4 near the ends. Just if you have time.